# Django Error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Action'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Action'.

I am getting this error when trying to submit a form. It works fine if i use the admnin page to add a post so the errror must be in the forms.

error only occurs when i click on one of the checkboxes

models.py:

```
class Genres(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = "Genres"
        ordering = ('name',)

class Post(models.Model):
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genres, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
genre_choices = Genres.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')

genre_choices_list = []

for item in genre_choices:
    genre_choices_list.append(item)

class NewPost(forms.ModelForm): 

    genres = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_multi'}),
                                     choices=genre_choices_list, required=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing names while should have pass ids. Try something like that:

```
genre_choices = Genres.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
```

Look at line above: now it returns `id` & `name` tuple instead of `name` & `name`. So, `MultipleChoiceField` takes id as a value not name